# how to convert dx10 dds image to png using DirectXTex

Tags: directx, textures, dxgi

I've been working with DirectXTex tools and was wondering if is possible to use `texconv.exe` backwards, to convert `DDS -> TGA` (or other supported format) instead of `TGA, BMP, PNG -> DDS`.
To convert PNG image to DDS can be done like this:

```
texconv -f <DXGI_FORMAT> source.png
```

I am looking for something like this:

```
texconv source.dds output.png
```

Or is there anything able to do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [DirectXTex](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex) library can certainly convert a `DDS` to another image format like `PNG`. Remember that the `DDS` file format is capable of encoding every possible Direct3D resource type and `DXGI_FORMAT`, but `PNG` is not.

If the `source.dds` in this case is a single image (i.e. no mipmaps, no arrays, no cube maps, not a volume map) and the format of the `source.dds` is a DXGI-equivalent of one of the [supported WIC pixel formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719797(v=vs.85).aspx#png__native_codec) for `PNG`, then this works:

```
texconv source.dds -ft png
```

Likely if it's encoded as a `DX10` extended header, it's not a WIC pixel format equivalent that's supported by the `PNG` codec, so you need to provide a conversion format. Something like:

```
texconv source.dds -ft png -f R8G8B8A8_UNORM
```

If `source.dds` has mipmaps, then those can easily be stripped out by using:

```
texconv source.dds -m 1 -ft png -f R8G8B8A8_UNORM
```

If the `source.dds` is a cubemap or a texture array, the problem is that `png` can't encode multiple images. You can get it to write as a TIFF which does support multi-image as:

```
texconv source.dds -m 1 -ft tif -f R8G8B8A8_UNORM
```

> I realized that the current behavior of the WIC writer to default to using multi-frame encoding is inconsistent with the behavior of the TGA and HDR writers which always write the first image. I added new behavior in [this commit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex/commit/1f05a8c2764785fa6b878acf08d1a98f5bfb6b2e) so that the WIC writer also defaults to writing just the first image unless you use `-wicmulti`. This will be in the next binary release, but currently you need to sync the master branch and build it yourself to get this new behavior.
>
> With the new version, to get a multiframe write you'd use `texconv source.dds -m 1 -ft tif -f R8G8B8A8_UNORM -wicmulti`. If you just want the first image, you can use `texconv source.dds -ft png -f R8G8B8A8_UNORM`. This also removes the need to explicitly use `-m 1` in the case where you just want the first image written.

When dealing with cubemaps, you can make use of the `texassemble` tool to convert it to a strip or a cross single image:

```
texassemble h-strip source.dds -o output.png -f R8G8B8A8_UNORM
```

If the `source.dds` is written using a `DXGI_FORMAT_*_SRGB` format, then when it writes a `PNG` it will encode the sRGB chunk to indicate the colorspace. This might or might not result in the expected appearance. You can explicitly convert it to a non-SRGB format (which is what will happen above), you can keep it in the sRGB colorspace by using `-f R8G8B8A8_UNORM_SRGB`, or you can use the `-srgbi` or `-srgbo` switches to 'cast' it to/from an sRGB format without changing the data.

If `source.dds` is a High-Dynamic Range texture (i.e. `R32G32B32A32_FLOAT` or the like), then the resulting image might get blown-out converting it to `R8G8B8A8_UNORM`. You can use the `-tonemap` switch in this case.

> See [Texconv](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex/wiki/Texconv) and [Texassemble](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex/wiki/Texassemble) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for great answer. You did mistake in first example, you wrote "=" instead of "-" :)  By the way, is there a way to set output (png) name or/& path ?

Comment: Thanks. Fixed the typo. I used the same design for the DirectXTex ``texconv`` as the original legacy DirectX SDK tool which is really for 'bulk conversion'. You can use ``-o`` to provide an output directory, ``-sx`` to add a filename suffix, and/or  ``-px`` to add a filename prefix.

Comment: Just found out, why paths containing spaces not working ? Like directory "My files" is considered as "My" "Files"